# Downloading large files (~400MB) stops prematurely in production, works fine on development server

Tags: php

Recently I ran into a problem on larger file downloads in PHP. PHP is running as CGI on zeus server. I tried everything but all in vain.  like:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

The problem is that after downloading about 4-5MB, downloading stops without any warning. However, when I run the code locally everything works like a charm. Help me get out of this problem.

Comment: You're using a commond gateway interface?

Comment: do you have enough space in `temp` folder? Is it stop always at 4-5mb even if whole file have 10mb for e.g.?

Comment: Downloading what with what?  cURL?  Accepting a POST?  file_get_contents?

Comment: I am providing a link to the loggedin user. After user click on that downloads a file from another domain ( apprx. 400mb ). The file is downloaded for only about 2 mins and stops. This happens with any file size which cant be downloaded within 2 mins on a 30-40 kbps internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your PHP.ini file on the zeus server and your local box.  Check the

```
upload_max_filesize = ??
```

Or the:

```
post_max_size = ??
```

values on both servers.  See if they are different.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a memory limitation of the CGI process or some other limitation in the response delivery chain.

- don't load the whole file into memory, e.g. `echo file_get_contents(<file>)`
- disable output compression for this request (PHP and Webserver)

I suggest you also read this [page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Could you paste the code that send the file?

Comment: I tried that, Rather I am spliting files into chunks and then echoing from the output buffer.

Comment: function download() {                     
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: '.$this->mimetype);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$this->filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $this->filesize);

        $this->readfile_chunked( $this->filepath );
        exit;                
    }

Comment: function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes=TRUE) {
        $chunk_size = 1024*1024;
        $buffer = '';
        $cnt =0;
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        if ( $handle === false ) {return false;}
        stream_set_timeout($handle, 3600);
        while (!feof($handle)) {
          $buffer = fread($handle, $chunk_size );          
          echo $buffer;
          ob_flush();
          flush();
          if ($retbytes) { $cnt += strlen($buffer);}
        }
        $status = fclose($handle);
        if ($retbytes && $status) {return $cnt;}
        return $status;
      }

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use:

```
post_max_size = ?
```

Best of luck!